# instructing one thread to execute code when triggered by another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

In my program I am invoking a thread with an ExecutorService that will run a block of code which will run behind the scenes of the application, sending events to the gui to update it. When a conditon is met at the end that tells the gui to reset the buttons and counts and the thread will end.

I start the thread by:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
executor.execute(new RunOnTimer(this));
// RunOnTimer starts a thread with that instance of the class
```

The thread will then run until the condition is met:

```
//if this
fireNoMoreFilesEvent();
```

which tells the gui to reset the and then the executor:

```
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

When I debug the running thread is killed and all that is left is the main thread. Now the issue is when I try to run the same execution again in the same instance of the program, the thread starts up then suddenly exits without executing any code. Then right after this happens I once again select the same code to execute and it works fine.

If I try to observe this behavior in debug, the code will run fine and the new thread doesnt just exit without executing anything so my guess is that there is something going on between the main thread the new thread when the new thread sends the events to the gui.

Is there some method of making the main thread execute code that would otherwise be done by the new thread? All I want is for the new thread to do its run block and send events for the gui. If this is possible, what are some methods of doing so?

Comment: Does the event set a flag that doesn't get cleared before you run the task again?

Answer (score 0):

If you're repeatedly running tasks in the executor then my advice is to create the executor once at the start of your program and then use the same one for every task. There's no value in creating multiple executors. Each one can execute multiple tasks. When constructing your task, pass in an object that the task can use to signal completion. Consider Future, CompletableFuture, or BlockingQueue. Also you might want CompletionService instead of ExecutorService.